# Image of bounded linear operator?

Tags: operator-theory

Let  $x^\ast$ be a  continuous linear functionals  on $l_p$. Let $(e_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ be the standard basis of $l_p$. Consider  $y=(y_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ the sequence defined by $y_i=x^\ast(e_i)$. Let $q>0$ be so that   $\frac 1p+\frac 1q=1\ \ (p\gt 1$). Define the sequence of elements in $l_p$, $x_n=(x_n^i)_{i\in \Bbb N} \in l_p$ such that $$x_n^i=\begin{cases}|y_i|^{q-1}{\rm sign} (y_i), \ \ i\le n \\ 0, \ \ i\gt n \end{cases} $$ Show that $x^\ast(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^q$.

I hope I've been clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one writes $x_n$ in the standard basis $(e_i)_{i\in {\mathbb N}}$, then
$$ x_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^{q-1}\, sign(y_i)\, e_i.$$
Since $x^*$ is a linear functional it follows
$$x^*(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^{q-1}\, sign(y_i)\, x^*(e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^{q-1}\, sign(y_i)\, |y_i|\, sign(y_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^{q}sign(y_i)^2.$$
I guess $l_p$ is over the field ${\mathbb R}$, so we conclude that
$$x^*(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^{q}.$$